# Class default parameter in python

Tags: python, oop

if I create a class called Car

```
class Car():
    '''car information summary'''
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer = 0
```

I learned that `self.odometer=0` allowed me creating a new instance without putting a value for odometer. Every new instance will start with an odometer reading at 0.

But what if I want to create an new instance with a specified odometer reading?

```
car_1 = Car('Audi', 'S4', '2017', 5000)
```

It won't allow me to do so. What I am trying to do is to use it like a default value for a function: You don't have to give a value because there is a default, but when you do, you can overwrite the default.

And I do understand that I can revise the attribute afterwards, or write a method to change the attribute. But that's not my concern for now.

Is this a wrong idea to have for OOP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python supports the concept of [*parameters with a default value*](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm). You can write a parameter, and give it a default value if it is not specified. In this case it looks like:

```
class Car():
    '''car information summary'''

    def __init__(self, make, model, year, odometer=0):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer = odometer
```

So in case you call it with three parameters, Python will see that you did not provide a value for the `odometer` parameter, and it will *implicitly* assign zero to it.

A point that sometimes causes confusion is that the **default values are only evaluated once**, at interpretation time, not each time you call the `__init__` function.

For example if we write:

```
def f(x=[]):
    return x
```

Then Python will evaluate `[]` only *once*. And each time you do not provide a value for `x`, you will obtain a reference to the *same* list (not a new list every time).

Therefore it is usally dangerous to use *mutable types* (an `int` is *not* a mutable type, so we are safe for the `odometer=0`).

If we thus for instance `.append(3)` to the outcome of `f()`, then from now on, `f()` will return that list (`[3]`). Which is usually not the intended effect. Some IDEs will give warnings if you use a mutable object.

If you want a *new* empty list each time `x` is not provided, a common pattern is:

```
def f(x=None):
    if x is None:
        x = []
    return x
```

Comment: got it!! Thanks!!

Comment: can you elaborate the last sentence with an example? I am not sure what it really means